# integrating unity.wcf with asp.net routes

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, unity-container

I am trying to use unity.wcf inside my wcf web services without an svc file.

My code:

```
 [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Required)]
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall, ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Single)]
//[BasicAuthentication] TODO: this need to be set up
public class SsoAuthenticationService : ISsoAuthenticationService
{
    private readonly ICustomerManager _manager;
    internal const string ServiceUri = "SsoAuthenticationService";

    public SsoAuthenticationService(ICustomerManager manager)
    {
        _manager = manager;
    }

    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "CreateSsoLogin/{request}")]
    public ServiceResponse<bool> CreateSsoLogin(string request)
    {
        // TODO: inputs and outputs are wrong
        _manager.DoWork();
        return new ServiceResponse<bool>();
    }
}

    public class ServiceFactory : UnityServiceHostFactory
{
    protected override void ConfigureContainer(Microsoft.Practices.Unity.IUnityContainer container)
    {
        container.RegisterType<ISsoAuthenticationService, SsoAuthenticationService>("authentication")
            .RegisterType<ICustomerManager, CustomerManager>();


    }
}
```

Now the problem comes when I try and connect the ServiceFactory class - in all the code examples I have seen they do this via an svc file, but I don't have one in my application, as it is using ASP.NET routing.

So my Global.asax looks like:

```
 private static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {

        //Integrate WCF services with the ASP.NET routing feature
        routes.Add(new ServiceRoute(SsoAuthenticationService.ServiceUri, new ServiceFactory(), typeof(SsoAuthenticationService)));
    }
```

When I call my web service method, I am not hitting the web method code (it does call ServiceFactory.ConfigureContainer though). If I weren't using Unity, the  Global.asax would look like:

```
 private static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {

        //Integrate WCF services with the ASP.NET routing feature
        routes.Add(new ServiceRoute(SsoAuthenticationService.ServiceUri, new WebServiceHostFactory(), typeof(SsoAuthenticationService)));
    }
```

And if I change it to this, then the web method is hit, but of course it complains about the constructor.

What extra configuration do I need to make the ServiceFactory class behave like WebServiceHostFactory?

Or would a better option be to not use Unity.Wcf, and try and implement with plain Unity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, I have managed to find the answer to this using the following link http://www.agile-code.com/blog/rest-web-services-with-unity-wcf/

I had to create a new pair of classes to inherit from WebServiceHostFactory (abstract) and WebServiceHost as described in the link.

Once these were in place, and my ServiceFactory class inherited from the new class, everything started working.